# Traceback error: TypeError float object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, typeerror

Could someone help me figure out the problem I have with this?

```
def marbles():
    marbles = 0
    while True:
        try:
            x = eval(input("How many marbles? "))
        except ValueError: 
            print("You can't enter", x , "marbles! How many marbles do you have?")
            continue
        else:
            break
    for i in range(x):
        x = eval(input("Please enter how many marbles between 0 and 100: "))
        if 0 <= x and x <= 100:
            marble = marble + x
        else:
            print("Your number is out of range!")
            y = int(input("Please enter how many marbles between 0 and 100: "))

main()
```

I can't seem to figure out why it won't give out the warning that You are not in range when I code 5.4 marbles. Between 0 and 100, I should be allowed to give decimals, but for "How many marbles" I would like to receive that warning to try again.

Comment: Why are you using `eval(input(...))` in some places (bad!) and `int(input(..))` in others? Note that if you want to evaluate *literals*, you should really use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html "Official documentation for the ast module.") module's [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval "Official documentation for literal_eval"). This function is like `eval` but doesn't interpret *arbitrary* code, but only python literals, making it safe to use with untrusted inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_integer()` method. It returns boolean if parameter is whole number or not.

For example

```
>>> (5.4).is_integer()
False
>>> (1).is_integer()
True
```

Check [this documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer)

Answer (score 0):

You need string's [isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method.
Something like this?

```
def marbles():
    marbles = 0
    count_flag = False
    while count_flag is False:
        try:
            x = raw_input("How many marbles? ")
            if not x.isdigit():
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print "You can't enter %s marbles! How many marbles do you have?" % (x)
        else:
            x = int(x)
            count_flag = True
    for i in range(x):
        x = int(input("Please enter how many marbles between 0 and 100: "))
        if 0 <= x and x <= 100:
            marbles = marbles + x
        else:
            print("Your number is out of range!")
            y = int(input("Please enter how many marbles between 0 and 100: "))

    return marbles

print marbles()
```

Also, in case of python, instead of doing 0<=x and x<=100, you can do either 0<=x<=100(my preference) or x in range(0, 101). Second one is not recommended though :-)

Also a flaw with your for statement logic. If a user gives two bad inputs, they are not considered. You need a while there also.

```
while x > 0:
   y = int(input("Please enter how many marbles between 0 and 100: "))
   if 0 <= y and y <= 100:
       marbles = marbles + y
       x -= 1
   else:
       print("Your number is out of range!")
```

To be honest, the cleaner practice would be to put the input validation in another function and call it in the marbles function.

```
def get_number(screen_input):
    flag = False
    while flag is False:
        try:
            x = raw_input(screen_input)
            if not x.isdigit():
                raise ValueEror
        except ValueError:
            print("You can't enter %s marbles! How many marbles do you have?" % (x))
        else:
            return int(x)

def marbles():
    marbles = 0
    x = get_number("How many marbles?")
    while x > 0:
        y = get_number("Please enter how many marbles between 0 and 100:")
        if 0 <= y <= 100:
            marbles += y
            x -= 1
        else:
            print("Your number is out of range!")
    return marbles

print marbles()
```